# What is the name of this control?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm a newbie in programming and also in winform, please forgive me if my question looks silly. I have a download manager (flashget) and I wish to use a similar control in my application.

Here is the control picture:

[image]

I just need to know name of the control and I will search the SDK for details.

Comment: @d-live, please upgrade your comment to an answer so that I can vote it up. Thanks for quick answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [**`ListView` control**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx), set to "Details" view and displaying the headers. The headers are created when you define the columns: Filename, Preview, Size, Percent, Speed, Resource, and Time left.

That *particular* control looks to be owner-drawn, as it uses a highlighting style that differs from the system default. It also has multiple images displayed for each list item, which isn't supported by the native control. To owner draw, you need to set the [`OwnerDraw` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw.aspx) to True, and write the code to handle drawing the ListView control yourself. Not necessarily an easy undertaking; it's better to make the built-in styles work for your application.